Is it possible to perform a "KDF flooding" attack to exhaust all contexts c of a KDF and make it unusable?
I'm actually working on KDF (Key Derivation Function) and specificialy on the HKDF paper from CRYPTO-2010.
Let's consider the following HKDF oracle : $KDF(\sigma, r, c, l)$ where :

$\sigma$ : Raw data from which the KDF is to derive the sub-keys
$r$ : Random salt (optionnal)
$c$ : Context information field (optionnal)
$l$ : Number of key bits to be produced by KDF

In the context of a KDF, where the attacker can freely choose values for the context parameter $c$, I wonder if it's possible to perform a "flooding" attack to exhaust all possible contexts.
Specifically, since we cannot reuse a context, every new context $c$ must not be part of the set $\{c_1, ..., c_{q'}\}$ where $q'$ is the maximum number of requests we can make to the oracle.
Such an attack would involve submitting a large number of queries with different context values $c$ with the goal of:

Exhausting the system's resources that run the KDF oracle
Generating so many keys associated with different contexts that the KDF becomes impractical to use in a real-world scenario. Context is optionnal but could be helpful in practice I guess.

My specific questions are as follows:

Is this scenario realistic in a properly (or not) designed system ? For example, could the size of the context $c$ or limits on KDF invocations make this attack unlikely ?
Are there known KDF implementations vulnerable to this kind of attack?

Thanks in advance for your insights!

If you mean designing a new KDF, there's not much that can be improved besides correcting design flaws with HMAC and automatic length prepending or appending of parameters to prevent ambiguity. And NIST specifies way too many options. As for the context, it may be hardcoded (no attacker control), and if it isn't, I highly doubt you'd be able to cause a denial of service attack by calling a KDF unless you're doing password hashing. Choosing the context doesn't affect the output being indistinguishable from random.

Ok, thanks for your answer, it's clearer rn !
